# wkhtmltopdf on aws cpanel

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cpanel, wkhtmltopdf

I was running wkhtmltopdf on my Windows local machine which was working fine. But now I hosted my website on aws(CentOS server) and tried to run, here it's not creating the .pdf file using wkhtmltppdf.

So Does it make a difference in installing wkhtmltopdf on windows and aws (linux I suppose) with same windows flavored version.

It is not able to pick up the link for the .exe file in cpanel as far as I understand, and shows http error 500 .

My code is

```
    require DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $html1 = $doc1->saveHTML();
    //echo $html1;

    use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;
    $pdf = new Pdf;
    $pdf->binary = '/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe';
    $pdf->addPage($html1);

    if (!$pdf->send()) {
      throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result); 
    exit();
```

I am trying to convert $html1 to pdf. The code is working fine when I uncomment "echo $html1", it shows editable html.So, I guess autoload. php is loading correctly, but when I comment "echo $html1" and want to convert this to pdf, it shows http 500 error.**strong text**

Comment: CentOS is Linux, you cannot run Windows `exe` files on Linux. Install `wkhtmltopdf` from command line downloading it from **[here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)** and point your PHP script to the correct binary.